# How to count unique occurences of Data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I am trying to count unique occurrences of a Client ID in the following code.

```
TRANSFORM Count(Research.Client_ID) AS CountOfClient_ID
SELECT Research.Treatment, Count(DCount("[Client_ID]","[Letter Status]")) AS [Total Letters Sent]
FROM Research INNER JOIN [Letter Status] ON Research.Client_ID = [Letter Status].Client_ID
GROUP BY Research.Treatment
PIVOT [Letter Status].Letter_Status;
```

The expression I think needs to be modified is:

```
Total Letters Sent: Count(DCount("[Client_ID]","[Letter Status]"))
```

The typical form for the DCount function is (**expression, domain,** **criteria**). I am pretty sure I need to specify, somehow, that the [Client_ID] should be unique in the **criteria** argument of the DCount function, but I don't know how. Is this possible?

Comment: The DCount description certainly sounds like it should have that capability, but I gave it a few tries and can't get it do that.  I recommend making a subquery to handle the distinct counting for you, and join onto that. A much uglier solution, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this query doesn't get what you want, please show us with sample data how it differs from what you want.

```
SELECT
    q.Treatment,
    Count(*) AS [Total Letters Sent]
FROM
    [SELECT DISTINCT
        Treatment,
        Client_ID
    FROM
        Research
    ]. AS q
GROUP BY
    q.Treatment;
```